# how to find un serialized objects in application

Tags: java, serialization, websphere

I am working with WebSphere and Struts hiberntae technology. My onsite team reported serialiazation problem while they were working.But i didn't faced the problem in my machine. Is there anything should i need to configure in server to figure out such errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) which will warn you for any serialization problem.

---

**Resources :**

- [Findbugs - SE warnings](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#SE_BAD_FIELD)

Comment: What do you mean replicate them ? You can test your code with FindBug, it's your team which will have to test later if the bug is still present.